# Sorting not working on click in react when using material-ui table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

By default, I'm able to display the data in ascending order. But, when I click on the table header, the column data should change to descending order and goes on alternatively.

**Load Data in ascending order -> On click, change to descending order -> Again on click, change to ascending -> loop continues.**

Here, getting the data from the api call as array of objects.

Able to load the data in ascending order, but when trying to change the order, it is not working.

```
import "../App.css";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import Table from "@mui/material/Table";
import TableBody from "@mui/material/TableBody";
import TableCell, { tableCellClasses } from "@mui/material/TableCell";
import TableContainer from "@mui/material/TableContainer";
import TableHead from "@mui/material/TableHead";
import TableRow from "@mui/material/TableRow";
import Paper from "@mui/material/Paper";
import { Grid } from "@mui/material";
import axios from "axios";

const App = () => {
  const StyledTableCell = styled(TableCell)(() => ({
    [`&.${tableCellClasses.head}`]: {
      fontStyle: "normal",
      fontWeight: 600,
      fontSize: "16px",
      width: "fit-content",
      whiteSpace: "nowrap",
      lineHeight: "24px",
    },
    [`&.${tableCellClasses.body}`]: {
      fontStyle: "normal",
      fontWeight: 600,
      fontSize: "16px",
      width: "fit-content",
      whiteSpace: "nowrap",
      overflow: "hidden",
      textOverflow: "ellipsis",
      lineHeight: "24px",
    },
  }));
  const StyledTableCellDown = styled(TableCell)(() => ({
    [`&.${tableCellClasses.head}`]: {
      fontStyle: "normal",
      fontWeight: 600,
      fontSize: "16px",
      lineHeight: "24px",
      minWidth: "200px",
    },
    [`&.${tableCellClasses.body}`]: {
      fontStyle: "normal",
      fontWeight: 600,
      fontSize: "16px",
      width: "fit-content",
      whiteSpace: "nowrap",
      overflow: "hidden",
      textOverflow: "ellipsis",
      lineHeight: "24px",
    },
  }));
  const StyledTableRow = styled(TableRow)(() => ({
    "&:nth-of-type(odd)": {
      fontStyle: "normal",
      fontWeight: 600,
      fontSize: "16px",
    },
  }));
  
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [order, setOrder] = useState('asc');

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://someapiurl")
      .then((response) => {
  if(response.data !== null && response.data !== undefined && response.data.length > 0) {
    data.sort((a, b) => a.name.toLowerCase() > b.name.toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1);
  }
        setData(response.data);
      });
  }, []);

  const sorting = (col) => {
    if(order === 'asc') {
      const sorted = data.sort((a,b) =>
        a[col].toLowerCase() < b[col].toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1
      );
      setData(sorted);
      setOrder('dsc');
    }
    if(order === 'dsc') {
      const sorted = data.sort((a,b) =>
        a[col].toLowerCase() > b[col].toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1
      );
      setData(sorted);
      setOrder('asc');
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Grid
        xs={12}
        md={12}
        lg={12}
        container
      >
        <Paper>
          <TableContainer>
            <Table stickyHeader aria-label="sticky table">
              <TableHead>
                <TableRow>
                  <StyledTableCell align="left" onClick={() => sorting("name")}>
                    Name
                  </StyledTableCell>
                  <StyledTableCell align="left">
                    Age
                  </StyledTableCell>
                </TableRow>
              </TableHead>
              <TableBody>
                {data && data.map((row) => (
                  <StyledTableRow key={row.name}>
                    <StyledTableCell align="left">
                      {row.name}
                    </StyledTableCell>
                    <StyledTableCell align="left">
                      {row.age}
                    </StyledTableCell>
                  </StyledTableRow>
                ))}
              </TableBody>
            </Table>
          </TableContainer>
        </Paper>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Hi @Inspond. Can you please describe what happens when the header is clicked? What does *not working* mean exactly? Are you seeing error messages or warnings in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below is executed on each re-render of the component. It sorts by category and overrides the sorting action of the table header.

```
if(data !== null && data !== undefined && data.length > 0) {
    data.sort((a, b) => a.category.toLowerCase() > b.category.toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1);
}
```

I assume this category sort was intended to be a default sort that happens once, when the data is first loaded from the API. If this is the case, the sort should be done inside the `useEffect`, just before the call to `setData`.

## Update

A small update is needed because when useEffect calls sort() in your updated code, it would sort the default, empty `data` array from useState, not the data that came from the API response.

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios
        .get("https://someapiurl")
        .then((response) => {
            let data = [];
            if(response.data !== null &&
                response.data !== undefined &&
                response.data.length > 0
            ) {
                data = response.data;
                data.sort((a, b) => a.name.toLowerCase() > b.name.toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1);
            }
            setData(data);
        });
}, []);
```

Comment: Yes, after this when I click on the header, the data's sort order should change to descending, but not changing and again on clicking the header, it should go back to ascending order data and this loop goes on when clicking on the header. For now, when clicking on the header, the data is still on the ascending order.

Comment: @Inspond I tested your code with some placeholder data. You can see the results in [this image](https://kofeigen.srht.site/so/so-76038128/table.gif). The ascending/descending order does change on each click. I used gender for the category. The category sort is the problem. In my image, you see that the order only changes among the women's names (Wilma and Betty). Do you think you are not seeing changes because of the category values in your data objects? Did you try the changes I suggested in my answer?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the code as you have suggested. Here, I wanted to sort the column based on name. I have misinterpreted the name as category. Can you check my updated code?

Comment: @Inspond The update is looking better. Just a small change needed. See my updated answer.

Comment: Your code is working for loading data in ascending order. After that, on clicking the column header, the data should change to descending order and vice-versa on every column header click, so this is the issue.

Comment: @Inspond Sorry, I did not understand your last comment. There might be confusion because my sample code was not loaded in ascending order (I just used dummy data). But, are any other changes needed? If everything is ok, you can mark my answer as accepted. Thanks.